# Limit of the sequence $x_n= [ (\frac{2}{1} ) (\frac{3}{2}) ^2 (\frac{4}{3}) ^3.....(\frac{n+1}{n})^n )]^\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Limit of the sequence $$x_n= [ (\frac{2}{1} ) (\frac{3}{2}) ^2  (\frac{4}{3}) ^3.....(\frac{n+1}{n})^n )]^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

I tried to cancel terms but it didn't work. Also tried to apply cauchy limit theorem. Is there any easy technique to attack these kind of problems? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write
$$
x_n=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \left(
1+\frac{1}{k}
\right)^k\right)^{1/n}
$$
so
$$
\log{x_n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k\log(1+k^{-1}).
$$
At this point you can use [stolz cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to deduce that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\log x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
which is a limit you should be able to compute.

Answer (score 2):

By cancelling terms we have
$$x_n=[\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}]^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$=\frac{n+1}{(n!)^{1/n}}$$
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{n+1}{(n!)^{1/n}}=e$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$x_n=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k\right)^{\frac 1n}$$

Define $$y_n=x_n^n=\prod_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k$$ Take logarithms and you will arrive to something you know very well.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_n=\left (\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n!}\right )^{1/n} \rightarrow e$$